# Calcular media aritmética de una matriz

Tags: c

`Hola buenas`, me piden que calcule la media aritmética de una matriz.

Tengo hecho lo siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 4

void llegir_matriu_de_teclat (float matriu [DIM][DIM]);
void imprimir_matriu (float matriu [DIM][DIM]);
int suma_diagonal (float matriu [DIM][DIM]);
int mitjanes_aritmetiques_triangles (float matriu [DIM][DIM]);

    void main () {

        float matriu [DIM][DIM];
        int res;

        printf ("Introdueix una matriu 4x4: ");
        llegir_matriu_de_teclat (matriu);
        imprimir_matriu (matriu);
        res = suma_diagonal (matriu);
        printf ("El resultat de la suma de la diagonal de la matriu és: %d\n", res);

        //FUNCIÓN QUE HACE LO INDICADO

        res = mitjanes_aritmetiques_triangles (matriu);
        printf ("La mitja aritmètica dels dos triangles és: %d", res);

    }

    void llegir_matriu_de_teclat (float matriu [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < DIM; i ++) {
            for (j = 0; j < DIM; j ++) {
                scanf ("%f", &matriu [i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    void imprimir_matriu (float matriu [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < DIM; i ++) {
            for (j = 0; j < DIM; j ++) {
                printf ("%6.1f", matriu [i][j]);
            }
            printf ("\n");
        }
    }

    int suma_diagonal (float matriu [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j, sum;

        sum = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < DIM; i ++) {
            j = i;
            sum = sum + matriu [i][j];
        }
        return (sum);
    }

    // FUNCIÓN QUE HACE LO INDICADO

    int mitjanes_aritmetiques_triangles (float matriu [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j, sum, cont, res;

        printf ("Aquesta és el triangle superior de la matriu: ");

        for (i = 0; i <= DIM - 2; i ++) {
                    for (j = i + 1; j <= DIM - 1; j ++) {
                        cont ++;
            }
        }

        printf ("\nAquesta és el triangle inferior de la matriu: ");

        for (i = 0; i <= DIM - 1; i ++) {
                    for (j = 0; j <= i - 1; j ++) {
                sum = matriu [i][j] ++;
                        cont ++;
            }
        }

        res = sum / cont;
        return (res);
        printf ("\n");
    }
```

Cabe destacar que de todo el programa, solo no me funciona la última función y la última parte del `void main`, pero pongo todo el código para que sea más legible y entendible.

De antemano, gracias y un saludo.

Comment: ¿ Esto cuantas preguntas son ? ¿ 4 ? ¿ 1 ? ¿ Ninguna ?

Comment: ¿ Se supone que la última función calcula la media ? Recordá que la [media aritmética](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticMean.html) es la suma de todos los valores divido entre el número de sumandos .

Comment: Es una única pregunta, Trauma.
La pregunta sale en el título.

Lo sé MlStud, es justo lo que intenté hacer ahí, que la media aritmética sea la suma de los valores divido entre el número de sumandos. Gracias por responder.

Comment: El título no es una pregunta; como mucho, es una orden. Usas claramente el verbo `calcular`. En mi tierra, es casi un imperativo. Sigo si ver la pregunta o el problema por ningún lado.

Comment: Trauma, eso es el enunciado. Al parecer nunca falta la gente como tú ... Para entrar aquí a tocar los cojones, mejor ni te molestes a responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu matriz es cuadrada, puedes calcular la media aritmética sumando los elementos de la matriz y dividiendo esa suma por la cantidad de elementos de la matriz, es decir, DIM * DIM. Por ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 3
void main(){

    float matriz[DIM][DIM] = {{3,4,5},{50,1,7},{0,9,8}};
    int fila, columna, sum = 0;
    float mediaAritmetica;

    for(fila = 0; fila < DIM; fila++){
        for(columna = 0; columna < DIM; columna++){
            sum += matriz[fila][columna];
        }
    }
    mediaAritmetica = sum/(float)(DIM * DIM);
    printf("La media aritmetica es: %.3f", mediaAritmetica);
}
```

Comment: Primero de todo, gracias por responder.
En primer lugar, ¿por qué lees la matriz entera? ¿No sería más eficiente leer solo la diagonal y calcular la media de esos valores?
¿Podrías explicarme qué es lo que hace el `DIM * DIM`, no lo he entendido.

Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Para calcular la media tienes que sumar todos los valores de la matriz, no sólo los de la diagonal. Es por esto que recorro toda la matriz, para sumar todos sus valores y después dividirlos por la cantidad de valores sumados, es decir, la cantidad de filas por la cantidad de columnas (por esto el DIM * DIM, estoy calculando la cantidad de elementos de la matriz, suponiendo que es una matriz cuadrada).